Is this a category? $F(A) \rightarrow B$
Algebras over a monad are well understood.
Consider a monad $(F, \mu, \eta)$ on $Set$.
$F$ is a functor, $F: Set \rightarrow Set$.
$\mu$ and $\eta$ are natural transformations.
There is a category called the Eilenberg Moore category where the objects are F-algebras in Set.  In that category, the F-algebra morphisms are of the type $F(A) \rightarrow B$ for sets $A$ and $B$.  I am interested in a specific example of the Distribution monad, where the functor $D$ takes sets to "sets of distributions on a set".  So, I am interested in a category whose morphisms are of type $D(A) \rightarrow B$, for $A, B \in Set$. I want to say things like this:
$$0.5 \vert UP \rangle + 0.5 \vert DOWN \rangle = b_1$$
Where $A = \{ UP, DOWN \} $ and $B = \{ b_1, b_2 \}$.
This doesn't invoke the normal details of the EM category, so there is a problem there.  Also, I don't have a way to do the summing over the set $A$ like you would do with real numbers (like if $A$, is $\mathbb{R}$).  Also, when you look at how complicated EM categories are, being F-algebras, the morphisms are algebra homomorphisms, what I am trying to do seems to skip over all of that to just get at the type of morphism which I am interested in, namely $F(A) \rightarrow B$.  I am just wondering how far I can get with this idea.  I just want a category whose morphisms are of that type and whose objects are sets.  Is this going to be possible?  What if I define a map from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and use that for the summing?

could you explain how $D$ is a monad, i.e. what are $\mu$ and $\eta$?

I have no idea what $0.5|Up\rangle+0.5|Down\rangle$ is supposed to be. This is a confusing post

Elienberg-Moore morphisms are of the type $A\to B$ (satisfying conditions), not of the type you write. That looks like a co-Kleisli category. I don't understand otherwise what the question is.
